# Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown> Error

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview, nestedscrollview, coordinator-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.shoaib.androideat.FoodDetail">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout" >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="#0e0d0e"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_food"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:title="Food Name"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btnCart"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/btnSignUp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:useCompatPadding="true"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout

            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                app:cardElevation="5dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/food_name"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:padding="12dp"
                        android:text="Food Name"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="20sp"

                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/layout_price"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_attach_money_black_24dp"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/food_price"
                            android:text="1,000"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </LinearLayout>


                    <com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton
                        android:id="@+id/number_button"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                        app:textSize="8sp"
                        app:backGroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        app:initialNumber="1"
                        app:finalNumber="20"

                        android:layout_height="30dp"/>



                </LinearLayout>



            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                app:cardElevation="5dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/food_description"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:text="Description"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Im using api 23 and this error I have I guess for xml file and some where I search I found something about "attr" , and Honestly I know anything about this

All of this code that you see is on the  " android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout "

there is my xml code and the error:

Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class  Error

Any Help Please???

Comment: I use this library in my gradel:

Comment: compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'